# iphone programming + memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leak  `theFileName = [[responseString lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];`

theFileName is a global variable. I have synthesized it and

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]))
    {
        // Custom initialization
        theFileName = [[NSString alloc] init];
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{

    //internally calls this function
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    //NSLog(@"the responsestring for download is:%@",responseString);
    theFileName = [[responseString lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    //NSLog(@"the theFileName for download is:%@",theFileName);
    //adds extension  .jpg to file name
    NSString *jpg=@".jpg";
    NSString *addjpg=[theFileName stringByAppendingString:jpg];
    //NSLog(@"append %@",addjpg);
}
```

Released it in dealloc.

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[thefileName release];
}
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are not calling dealloc, and how did you determine this is related to your memory leak?

Comment: @James: Of course, to be clear, you don't ever call `-dealloc` yourself except on `super` within self's `dealloc`. Speaking of which, you're also not calling `dealloc` on `super`.

Comment: @SK9 - Thank you. I am used to C/C++ and just started on Monday with doing programming with Objective-C.

Comment: @James: Correct me as I may be wrong, but `dealloc` is akin to the deconstructor in `C++` and you don't ever call this yourself. Instead, in `C++` its called automatically when you declare `delete` if I remember right. Good luck and enjoy your study - I learned a ton from this site! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few things that might help.

1. You're not calling `super`'s `dealloc` method within `self`'s `dealloc`. For example,

   `- (void) dealloc
   {
   [self.theFileName release];
   [super dealloc];
   }`
2. You're not using the getters and setters that come with synthesizing a property, and we don't know what property you've used with theFileName. If you've got a retaining property, i.e. a statement like `@property (copy) NSString * theFileName` then you should use the setter so that you don't trip up on retain counts. For example,

   - (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
     {
     if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]))
     {
         // Custom initialization
         NSString * aFileName = [[NSString alloc] init];
         [self setTheFileName:aFileName];
         [aFileName release];
     }
     return self;
     }

is better.

Answer (score 3):

```
theFileName = [[responseString lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

creates a new object for `theFileName`, which already holds an `NSString` object. You need to `release` that old value before, i.e.

```
[theFileName release];
theFileName = [[responseString lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

You might consider using a `copy` (recommended) or `retain` property for `theFilename`, and use the dot-syntax in `requestFinished:`.

Comment: @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *theFileName;This is how i am assigning the property.

Comment: Then just use self.theFileName  = [[responseString ...] ...];